# Not getting setProperty method for System Class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I had just started to write a selenium automation script but am not getting the required setProperty method for System class which is required to set the driver path

Please refer the this image :[Not getting setProperty method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wG9X.png)

Is this some issue with my Java setup in Eclipse?
Kindly Let me know if anyone knows why this is happening

Comment: It's your scope. Eclipse thinks you're attempting to declare something, so it won't show you the exposed properties or methods of `System` in the auto-complete. You'd have to do it within the scope of a method/initializer/constructor.

Comment: I can't see any code, hard to help :-( (images are good as a backup, put very hard to copy&paste, read, change, ....)

Comment: As Carlos tries to point out, don't post images of code. Even worse are images of code behind a link that's probably gonna break sometime soon. Next time just copy the actual code and paste it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work like that.

You'd have to write one static or instance method, and inside that you can write:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\***\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Using raw Selenium and Java, you could create a main method and set the system property:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\***\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\geckodriver.exe");
    }
```

Or if you are using **TestNG** then you could do something like this:

```
public class NewTest {

     public WebDriver driver;

     @BeforeClass
      public void beforeClass() {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\***\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\geckodriver.exe");
         driver =  new FirefoxDriver();

      }

      @Test
      public void openMyBlog() {
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            System.out.println("This is first test");
      }
}
```